# How are objects in New General Catalogue ordered?

Tags: ngc

How are objects in New General Catalogue ordered? Do the numbers themself have any meaning? What about other well-known catalogues?

Comment: They are ordered by ascending right ascension.

Comment: "by ascending right ascension" ... in the original equinox, that is 1860